# Prove that irreducible curve of bidegree $(1, n)$ is rational for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, projective-geometry

I'm meant to prove that irreducible curve of bidegree $(1, n)$ is rational for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I have a proof for this statement that uses the genus formula to show that such a curve must have genus $0$ and so is isomorphic to a $\mathbb{P}^1$, but I'm curious how one might prove this statement directly without reference to genus. Any help is welcome.

Comment: First, you obviously don't intend to have the word "rational" 6 words in. What about projecting it onto the first factor of $\Bbb P^1\times\Bbb P^1$?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I meant "irreducible"

Comment: So projection onto the first coordinate seems like a good place to start. Since our curve is of bidegree $(1, n)$, we should get a $\mathbb{P}^1$ in the first coordinate, no?

Comment: Well, you have one when you project on the second factor, too. But the projection has degree $1$ when we project onto the first factor, degree $n$ onto the second.

Comment: I don't really see how this leads to the result. Can you elaborate?

Comment: If you have a degree $1$ map from a curve to $\Bbb P^1$, then it must be an isomorphism. This follows from Riemann-Hurwitz (which brings us bavk to genus, but without adjunction) or from Riemann-Roch. But, more basically from the standpoint of complex analysis, it must be a globally $1$-to-$1$ map and hence is a biholomorphism.